# Gmail filter stopped working

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, mailing-list

I'm studying in a Russian non-technical University now, where we don’t have a normal mailing list to get emails from teachers and from each other.

I've created an account on Gmail and sent that address to all our teachers. Then I've created 20 filters to forward any incoming email to 20 classmates (Gmail limit). And I've created a rule to resend emails to another Gmail address. This address has similar filters to forward to other classmates' accounts. In the end, all 35 students can receive teachers' emails.

Everything was OK till this September.

During the vacation this scheme stopped working: filters do not run anymore. Filters are very simple (if * forward to name@qwe.ru). Only direct forwarding to one address works. Looks like Gmail blocked this option for my "mailing list."

So, how can I fix forwarding by a filter?

Comment: Why don't use a Google Groups and and use it as a distribution list? http://www.timeatlas.com/email/general/creating_distribution_lists_in_gmail

Comment: Can I use GoogleGroups if lots of my classmates don't have google accounts?

Comment: From Google Help:

The following Google Group tasks do not require a Google Account:

Reading posts in a public group.
Searching for groups, posts, or authors.
Posting to a group using email (if the group is unrestricted or you're already a member).
Joining a public Google Group using email.

http://support.google.com/groups/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=46438

Comment: You have to set up the Gorup so it send an email to its participants every time something is posted (a post is for example when you send an email to the group). So if your teachers send an email to the group, the group will send an email to the people